# Get Stream from Imagesource

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to get a Stream from a StreamImageSource.
I took a pic with the phonecamera and show a little preview on the form. Therefore I load the picture stream in a ImageSource.

Now I want to get back the Stream ... but with my approach I always get an exception that "Cannot access a closed Stream"

```
    private static async Task<Stream> GetStreamFromImageSourceAsync(StreamImageSource imageSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (imageSource.Stream != null)
        {
            return await imageSource.Stream(cancellationToken);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the caller routine

```
var s = await GetStreamFromImageSourceAsync((StreamImageSource)item.Source);                        
s.Position = 0;
```

and here i get the exception that i cannot read from a closed stream

thank you guys ...

Comment: You can't.  You need to take the original image from the camera and save it so you can reference it later.

Answer (score 3):

Once the Stream is consumed to display the preview, it gets closed and you can't use it anymore.

What you can do is, once you get the Stream from the camera, copy it in a `MemoryStream`, and that `MemoryStream` can be used and reused at will.